# MongoDB $max does not work as expected returning an empty array in nested object

Tags: mongodb

Here's the MongoDB Query im running:

```
db.contracts.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        quotation_subtotal_max:{ "$max":"$quotation.subtotal" },
        quotation_subtotal_min:{ "$min":"$quotation.subtotal" },
        quotation_subtotal_avg:{ "$avg":"$quotation.subtotal" },
        quotation_subtotal_sum:{ "$sum":"$quotation.subtotal" },
        works_package_max:{ "$max":"$works.package.price" },
        works_package_min:{ "$min":"$works.package.price" },
        works_package_avg:{ "$avg":"$works.package.price" },
        works_package_sum:{ "$sum":"$works.package.price" },
        sum:{ "$sum":1 },
    }
}])
```

The result i get back is:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "quotation_subtotal_max" : 87980.0,
    "quotation_subtotal_min" : 4030.0,
    "quotation_subtotal_avg" : 34636.7681818182,
    "quotation_subtotal_sum" : 762008.9,
    "works_package_max" : [],
    "works_package_min" : 11388.0,
    "works_package_avg" : 15138.0,
    "works_package_sum" : 30276.0,
    "sum" : 23.0
}
```

Structure of my JSON object in MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b0de14152588bb75175502"),
    "quotation" : {
        "subtotal" : 80883.0,
    },
    "works" : {
        "package" : {
            "price" : 18888.0,
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Package A",
                    "price" : 18888.0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using MongoDB 3.2.

Why does $max return an empty array for "works_package_max"?
I did 2-level nested it worked perfectly fine.
But when I did 3-level nested only $max doesn't work.
$min $avg $sum works as expected for both 2-level and 3-level nesting.

*UPDATE 1*

So what's happening is that i have 23 documents in my collection. 22 of the documents look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b0de14152588bb75175502"),
    "quotation" : {
        "subtotal" : 80883.0,
    },
    "works" : {
        "package" : {
            "price" : 18888.0,
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Package A",
                    "price" : 18888.0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but one documents looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b0de14152588bb75175502"),
    "quotation" : {
        "subtotal" : 80883.0,
    },
    "works" : []
}
```

because this document has no "works" so it's just an empty array, but this causes  $max to become an [] but doesn't cause a problem for $min $avg $sum, why is that so?

Is there a way to fix this by filtering out those documents where the "works" is empty?

Comment: I run this query it working fine and giving me your desired result

Comment: I didn't give the complete set of data. that is just the structure. anyway, i found the reason why. i will update my question.

Comment: Take a closer look at your data. There will actually be an array stored at `works.package.price` in at least one document. You can probably test this with `db.contracts.find({ "$where": "this.works.package.price instanceof Array" })`.

Comment: I see you found it already. So that's the problem. Bottom line is you either need to exclude documents where there is an array field or replace the value using `$ifNull` before passing it to `$max`. An "Array" is larger in BSON value than any numeric result. That is why `$max` returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add $match pipeline operator to filter those documents where nested sub document "works.package.price" doesn't exists.

```
 db.contracts.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
                   "works.package.price": { "$exists" : 1 }
                 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            quotation_subtotal_max:{ "$max":"$quotation.subtotal" },
            quotation_subtotal_min:{ "$min":"$quotation.subtotal" },
            quotation_subtotal_avg:{ "$avg":"$quotation.subtotal" },
            quotation_subtotal_sum:{ "$sum":"$quotation.subtotal" },
            works_package_max:{ "$max":"$works.package.price" },
            works_package_min:{ "$min":"$works.package.price" },
            works_package_avg:{ "$avg":"$works.package.price" },
            works_package_sum:{ "$sum":"$works.package.price" },
            sum:{ "$sum":1 },
        }
    }])
```

Comment: any idea why [] would break $max but not $max $avg and $sum?